# -ing nominals versus derived nominals

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Can we form -ing Argument Structure nominals that are derived from the following sentences? If so, what is the semantic difference between derived nominals and -ing nominals based on the given examples?

1. The barbarians destroyed Rome.

   a. the destruction of Rome by the barbarians.

   b. the destroying of Rome by the barbarians.
2. Tom loves Mary.

   a. Tom's love of Mary.

   b.the loving of Mary by Tom.

Comment: _Ing_ nominals are not that common, and they're lexical items like any other, so they have their own contexts and uses; they can't be made up on the spot like the examples above, which are very odd. If you don't use the ordinary word and use a novel construction instead, it draws attention from what you want to say.